# Return index if if it exists within the target in an array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array in which I need to return the index if it exists within the array. I think that I am on the right track however I am confused on how I should return my target index to actually produce what I am trying to return. If the index doesn't exist it should return -1 and if multiple targets are found the first occurrence should be returned.  The code that I have currently written is below.

```
public int getIndex(String target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length;i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) { 
            if (arr[i][j] == target) { 
               return target;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a multiple dimensional array, therefore, there is no such thing as "return the index". You have 2 indices.

Comment: When you write `return target;`, you are returning the value stored at indices `[i][j]` in the "matrix" `arr`, not either one of the indices nor something computed from both indices (such as `column + row*column_count` that maps a 2-dimensional pair of indices to a 1-dimensional index). Your question is a little vague. Are you sure `arr` is 2-dimensional? If so, what precise language was used to describe what must be returned?